# Trying to set up CAS with my Laravel project

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, cas

I am using [subfission/cas](https://github.com/subfission/cas) for my application. I have followed all [installation steps](https://github.com/subfission/cas/wiki/Installation). I am using windows, if that matters. More precisely, I have configured the following:

I ran the following in my terminal

```
composer require "subfission/cas" "dev-master"
```

I configured my Kernel.php accordingly, adding the following:

```
'cas.auth'  => 'Subfission\Cas\Middleware\CASAuth',
'cas.guest' => 'Subfission\Cas\Middleware\RedirectCASAuthenticated',
```

I ran the following command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

I also set up my cas server in my cas.php config file:

```
'cas_hostname'        => env('CAS_HOSTNAME', 'cas.myserver.me'),
'cas_real_hosts'      => env('CAS_REAL_HOSTS', 'cas.myserver.me'),
```

What I want is a middleware for all my routes, so I added the following route rule in my routes:

```
Route::middleware(['cas.auth'])->group(function ()
{
    Route::get('/', function ()
    {
        return view('welcome');
    });
});
```

Basically, I want to redirect everyone who is not logged in to the login page whenever I access the main page (for now, I will add more routes in the future). What happens is that the users are redirected to the login page when they are not logged in, but after the login I receive the following error:

> ErrorException (E_WARNING)
>   DOMDocument::loadXML(): Opening and ending tag mismatch: hr line 1 and body in Entity, line: 1

No matter what view I'm redirecting the user to. I tried the default welcome page as well as an empty view, but I still get the same error.

EDIT: I have used the dev-master branch from subfission/cas for the above error and after switching to 2.1.1, I get a different error:

> session_name(): Cannot change session name when headers already sent

EDIT 2: I did some more digging and I enabled internal errors in my cas client class with:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
```

And now I get the following:

```
Authentication failure: SA not validated Reason: bad response from the CAS server
```

And the cas response is:
[image: Cas error]
The thing is that I use the same cas server for another 2 projects and it works well for those (but those aren't laravel projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by disabling the SAML in the cas configure file:

```
'cas_enable_saml'     => env('CAS_ENABLE_SAML', true),
```

change to

```
'cas_enable_saml'     => env('CAS_ENABLE_SAML', false),
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been a while, but for anyone else having issues like this, the issue is the protocol selected for which your web service communicates with your CAS(Central Authentication Service) provider.  There are two main protocols used for SSO/CAS in this package:

1. SAML(Security Assertion Markup Language) version 1.1 & 2
2. CAS Protocol v3.0

*[Confusingly enough, CAS protocol shares the same namespace as the service.]*

The idea is to match the protocol and version with your identity provider. It sounds like your provider is using CASv3.0, which is why disabling SAML worked.

Also, if you enable debug mode, you will see further error details in your log file to help your troubleshoot.

Best of luck!